# scala groupby different class

Tags: scala

I have a `list` which may contain three different types of class, and all extends from class `E`, such as `A extends E`, `B extends E` and `C extends E`. And I need to identify each element in the `list` and do some calculations accordingly. (`list` may contain a little more subclass of `E` in the future.)

I prefer to use `map` or `partition` or `groupBy` rather than just `if`, but i get more confused right now. As I am very new to Scala, if anyone can share some idea? Thank you!

```
val list = //some codes to get the list//
list.groupby{
  _.getClass  //so in this line, is it possible to call the calculation method accordingly?
}

trait A extends E {
  def calA = {...}
}

trait B {
  def calB = {...}
}
trait C {
  def calC = {...}
}
```

Comment: Why isn't the `cal` behaviour encapsulated in your classes? Perhaps you could declare a `cal` method in `E`, override it accordingly in `A`, `B` and `C` and just call it. Let the sub-types handle the differences. Alternatively, if you really need/want to do matching by types in Scala, you could use [case classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/107).

Comment: @toniedzwiedz `E` cannot be modified right now, so some codes are needed to done in the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern matching handle the different classes:

```
val list = List(1, "s", "t")
list map {
  case a: A => a.calA
  case b: B => b.calB
  case i: Int => i + 5
  case s: String => s.toUpperCase
}
// -> List(6, "S", "T")

list groupBy {
  case a: E => "E" // grouping A, B and C together
  case i: Int => "Int"
  case s: String => "String"
}
// -> Map("Int" -> List(1), "String" -> List("s", "t"))
```

Comment: I think you can simplify the code a bit: `groupBy { v => v match { case ... } }`  becomes `groupBy { case ... }`

Comment: @dwickern Good spot. Jimmy, that's called pattern matching anonymous function, where we drop `match` to make the code clearer.